# Copying of invoices using vba

Tags: vba

I would like to know how I can copy multiple invoice details like, Customer Names, Delivery address from sheet 1 onto a Invoice template. I want to be able to create a new sheet that has all the invoice details on a invoice template. Like A2 to A10 has Customer Name, B2 to B10 has Delivery Address and so on.

Comment: How about mail merge, you can probably setup a mail merge via vba.

Answer (score 0):

Better question. Why would you do it this way ? What is your setup, do you have an excel spreadsheet that is already an invoice and you're keeping all your invoices in one workbook ?

Because you know, Sage Software puts out a very nice piece of accounting software that would let you do precisely what you're talking about by setting up a list of accounts and customers.

Ok an update to the original answer I gave you years back. "Now peachtree is 50 cloud accounting". no. no. no.

https://www.gnucash.org/download.phtml

Try this instead.

Answer (score 0):

The macro recorder creates VBA

Start the macro recorder

copy each cell from the source to the destination

Stop the recorder

Edit the macro to tweak the code to iron out any bugs.